# Move entire row to another sheet using time based action rather than onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following code to move an entire row of data from one sheet to another, which works perfectly.

I am using AppSheet for users to access and edit the data which blocks the onEdit function in Sheets. AppSheet have suggested that I change this script to a "time based trigger" so that edits within the app have the same action as editing the column directly in "Sheets"

Is there a way to easily do this?

Thank you in advanced!

```
    function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Needed
  // target sheet of move to named Acquired
  // test column with yes/no is col 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Stock" && r.getColumn() == 14 && r.getValue() == "Booked") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Bookings");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the function name is `onEdit()` which means it's an edit trigger based function. In other words, it's supposed to get triggered and executed in each edit.
But now you want it to be based on time and not on edit. So you can rename the function and create a time based trigger from top menu for this function.

Steps :

1. Rename `onEdit()` function. Maybe you can rename it to `moveRow()`
2. Select a `time based trigger` from top menu bar.
3. Choose suitable schedule and this function from drop down.
4. Save the changes.

Make sure you have given appropriate permissions. You can check this by trying to run the function once manually(By selecting it from top Select function drop down and clicking run/execute icon).

Comment: Hi Umair! Thank you for responding. I did try that, however, lines 6 & 7 return an error as that is an "event source". Sorry if it seems like a dumb question as I am a total newbie to this but is there an alternative for get source? I tried removing the event part of the source and it returned errors as well

Comment: Event object comes only when it's triggered by some edit or change, inside that object there is data about where, what, etc kind of edit or change have been made. Since time-based trigger is based on time and not on edit or change, So it'll not send any event object.
Maybe I'll be able to help you more in removing event object if you can explain me what you want to achieve as end goal.